# Django or web.py, which is better to build a large website with Python?

Tags: python, django, web.py

I'd like to use Python to build a website with more than 100,000 PV each day. Now what I concern is to choose which web framework. I know lots of people use Django, and some people use web.py. Django seems powerful, and I also like the simplicity of web.py. Which framework should I use? (Please introduce the performance and the maintenance complexity, thanks!) Can web.py build complicated applications? Are there other frameworks better than these two?

Comment: Is this a legacy application with a new web frontend or something you're building from the ground up?

Comment: It seems more people are familiar with Django. Are there any people who know web.py?

Comment: This is a new application building from ground up.

Comment: Webpy and Storm ORM is a great minimal combination. Then use Jinja2 for templating and Kabaam! You are free to create without learning a new language called Django... Instead you get to work in Python.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Django makes building complicated sites really simple.  Before Django, I was messing around with PHP, and I was doing a really terrible job putting it together.  Django leads you in the right direction with some good practices which makes your site really easy to maintain and update.  I really like the ORM and how you can easily work with data from the database without having to write a single line of SQL.  It makes development less of a slog.

I don't have any experience with web.py, and I can't compare the performance of the two.  But you can't go wrong with Django at least.

Comment: Webpy and Storm ORM is a great minimal combination.  Then use Jinja2 for templating and Kabaam!  You are free to create without learning a new language called Django...  Instead you get to work in Python.

Comment: I see those two as the most opossite possible options. Django is Django, over Python, and Web.py is Python itself.

Django is fullfit of modules (also 3rd party), but adds a bunch of files and configs to handle that functionallity. Also you need to learn "Django".

The real diference is being driven with relative easy, or do yourself in the shortest way possible, just python. Learning another language is not in my plans, still have to polish python :) so web.py is perfect for.

Comment: Well, answering this question is questionable if you have experience with only one of the frameworks.

Answer (score 16):

In case you haven't started yet, Give both frameworks a try. I started off with Django and moved to web.py.

Web.py is not that hard as one might think. In fact, I find it easier to work with than with Django!

Just my 2 cents.

EDIT: Also, this might help: http://www.aaronsw.com/weblog/rewritingreddit

Comment: Yes I also use web.py as it is quite nice. But today nginx with some cgi modules (there are some you can find) is also fast. Depending on what system you will use. I am using my Raspberry Pi 2 as the server and nginx is doing fine.

Comment: It is important to not confuse web.py to web2py. Web2py looks awesome too.

Comment: that rant didn't aged well, arguments like the curly braces and the packages to import seem off-place even for 2011

Answer (score 7):

Django is actually quite fast. Using caches and multiple DB backends is a doodle - you actually can utilize Django's predefined caching framework for one-line view caching or even template fragment caching. And of course - low-level cache API. And - it's fun!

In my experience - deployed under nginx and uWSGI, watched over by Supervisord, with the recently hot Celery task queueing package – Django is blazingly fast, easy to scale and configure and very reliable.

Answer (score 1):

forget all those, if you want a beautiful framework look for weppy, i have used django , web2py, bottle,flask and most major php frameworks, just use weppy its full stack and exquisitely elegant, for php i simply created my own microframework that looks abit like weppy but its not fullstack, i love the granular control that weppy gives me and its quite easy to learn and its such a joy to use, eer did i already say that its beautiful? yes it surely is hahaha. you can find it here : http://www.weppy.org thank me later

Comment: and then when it comes to performance, weppy is in a league by itself, no other framework comes even close